# apache derby termporary table accessible to multiple connections?

Tags: database, jvm, derby

Apache derby allows the creation of global temporary tables, but it appears that these tables are only accessible to the connection/session which created the temporary table.

Our system uses connection pooling, and there is no guarantee the the next query will use the same connection.  Is there anyway to define a temporary table as "global" in the sense that it is accessible to all connections to that database?

The docs state :  "The DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE statement defines a temporary table for the current connection."

It is not clear what "global" means in this context.  Link to docs : https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefdeclaretemptable.html